# Transparent btn-success

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button

How should I do to have this button but in green and without the green border?
For example, the `btn-delete` is red and without the red border.

```html
<!-- Bootstrap + Material Icons + jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button class="btn btn-link btn-success">
  <i class="material-icons">restore_from_trash</i>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

now u need to remove class 'btn-success' from button and add class 'text-success' to icon to get green color.

```html
<!-- Bootstrap + Material Icons + jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button class="btn border-0">
  <i class="material-icons text-success">restore_from_trash</i>
</button>
```

Comment: Ok, but I also want the button to be green (just like the `btn-delete` is red).

Comment: but you need to do more charges for states

Comment: button means? icon? or button element? Not clear, u need button green or transparent? if u need it green not Transparent. then remove the 'btn-link' class

Comment: The material icon is inside of the button. The background needs to be transparent ant the trash needs to be green.

Answer (score 0):

See the below, check if this is what you need

```html
<!-- Bootstrap + Material Icons + jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <style>
 .btn-success.myCustomSuccessbtn i {
   color:green;
 }
 .btn-success.myCustomSuccessbtn:active i {
   color: white;
  }
 </style>
<button class="btn btn-link btn-success border-0 myCustomSuccessbtn">
  <i class="material-icons">restore_from_trash</i>
</button>
```

Comment: You can't do everything he asked only with bootstrap classes. You need css at some point